# How to get sum of many div height using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

HTML div contain dynamic data, For calculate div height i used

```
var pageSize = 990;
    var clientHeight = 300;
    clientHeight = document.getElementById('testing1').clientHeight;
    var selector_classes = ['career_sum', 'exp_cal', 'ref_cal', 'port_cal', 'curri_cal', 'certi_cal'];
    selector_classes.forEach(function(element) {
        clientHeight = document.getElementById('testing').clientHeight + clientHeight;
    });
```

Testing is same id for div

That working fine. My question is how can i set style for those div which position greater than pagesize?
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `clientWidth` of body

```
let pageWidth = document.body.clientWidth;

selector_classes.forEach(function(element) {
       clientHeight = document.getElementById('testing').clientHeight + clientHeight;
       if(clientHeight > pageWidth) element.style.color = "red";
});
```

Comment: element.style.color = "red"; not working. If put the document.getElementById('testing').style.color = "red"; applying style only for first div :(  @Maheer Ali